# How do you configure custom claim attributes for username recovery in wso2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

According to WSO2 documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Username+Recovery) we can add additional attributes to the Username Recovery. I have selected an attribute and it displays on the Username Recovery form, but it does not appear to be used in the search filter to find the account.

The only field that it appears to use properly is email. Unfortunately, I need to include an additional attribute to distinguish between accounts.

What am I missing to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a WSO2 identity server 5.7, it is a reported [issue](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/2380). It has been fixed in IS-5.9 onwards. You can patch the fix by applying the changes in [2](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/2380), to get it to work in IS-5.7

[1](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/2380) -https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/6158

[2](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/2380) -https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/pull/2380

Comment: Thank you for the response. That patch worked well.

Comment: It appears that the recovery searches the user store per attribute instead of combined. For instance instead of a single search of: (&(objectClass=user)(sn=surname)(otherEmail=otheremail)), it searches (&(objectClass=user)(sn=surname)) then again with (&(objectClass=user)(otherEmail=otheremail)).  Does this seem accurate and is this changed in a patch or newer release?